# How to access parent's parent's methods from a en extended class?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I was studying the Inheritance concept in OOP in PHP as documented in [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php).

I came to know about various Features of inheritance in PHP like a class cannot inherit multiple classes   and to overcome this we should use `traits`.

Similarly I came to a point which got my head banging. In PHP if we do multiple level inheritance like

```
class A {
        // more code here
}

class B extends A {
        // more code here
}

class C extends B {
        // more code here
}

class D extends C {
        // more code here
}

// and so on ........
```

so like this the classes can be further extended to multiple levels but I am wondering how we can call the top most parent class method from the bottom most child. I know we can use `parent::methodName()` to call the immediate parent function from child class but if there are in depth inheritance of n levels then how can we determine the parent class method from child class for example calling `A::method` from child `D`, and similarly call method of `A` from `Z`.

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible, but I'm also curious if there might be a solution anyhow!

Comment: It something (AFAIK) that you shouldn't be concerned with.  If you call the parent method then that can decide how or if it wants to pass on the call to it's parent or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this.

And attempting to do something like this would just show that there are problems in your inheritance model.

If a `C` extends `B` which extends `A`, whatever "original" methods of `A` are no longer relevant for `C`. If they *are* relevant, maybe one should have extended `A` in the first place.

Generally, try not to abuse inheritance too much. It's [ripe](https://hackernoon.com/inheritance-based-on-internal-structure-is-evil-7474cc8e64dc) [with](https://blog.berniesumption.com/software/inheritance-is-evil-and-must-be-destroyed/index.html) [problems](https://codeburst.io/inheritance-is-evil-stop-using-it-6c4f1caf5117), and generally you should prefer composition over inheritance.

Comment: i was just trying to understand the concept behind this and therefore was just wondering the use case.